# $0 empty in script when run by cronjob

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-ebs

I am trying to setup automated backups for an AWS EBS volume and using https://github.com/colinbjohnson/aws-missing-tools/tree/master/ec2-automate-backup to do so.

The backup script used is the following (ec2-automate-backup.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash -
#confirms that executables required for succesful script execution are 
available
prerequisite_check() {
  for prerequisite in basename cut date aws; do
    #use of "hash" chosen as it is a shell builtin and will add programs to hash table, possibly speeding execution. Use of type also considered - open to suggestions.
    hash $prerequisite &> /dev/null
    if [[ $? == 1 ]]; then #has exits with exit status of 70, executable was not found
      echo "In order to use $app_name, the executable \"$prerequisite\" must be installed." 1>&2 ; exit 70
    fi
  done
}

#get_EBS_List gets a list of available EBS instances depending upon the selection_method of EBS selection that is provided by user input
get_EBS_List() {
  case $selection_method in
    volumeid)
      if [[ -z $volumeid ]]; then
        echo "The selection method \"volumeid\" (which is $app_name's default selection_method of operation or requested by using the -s volumeid parameter) requires a volumeid (-v volumeid) for operation. Correct usage is as follows: \"-v vol-6d6a0527\",\"-s volumeid -v vol-6d6a0527\" or \"-v \"vol-6d6a0527 vol-636a0112\"\" if multiple volumes are to be selected." 1>&2 ; exit 64
      fi
      ebs_selection_string="--volume-ids $volumeid"
      ;;
    tag)
      if [[ -z $tag ]]; then
        echo "The selected selection_method \"tag\" (-s tag) requires a valid tag (-t Backup,Values=true) for operation. Correct usage is as follows: \"-s tag -t Backup,Values=true.\"" 1>&2 ; exit 64
      fi
      ebs_selection_string="--filters Name=tag:$tag"
      ;;
    *) echo "If you specify a selection_method (-s selection_method) for selecting EBS volumes you must select either \"volumeid\" (-s volumeid) or \"tag\" (-s tag)." 1>&2 ; exit 64 ;;
  esac
  #creates a list of all ebs volumes that match the selection string from above
  ebs_backup_list=$(aws ec2 describe-volumes --region $region $ebs_selection_string --output text --query 'Volumes[*].VolumeId')
  #takes the output of the previous command 
  ebs_backup_list_result=$(echo $?)
  if [[ $ebs_backup_list_result -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "An error occurred when running ec2-describe-volumes. The error returned is below:\n$ebs_backup_list_complete" 1>&2 ; exit 70
  fi
}

create_EBS_Snapshot_Tags() {
  #snapshot tags holds all tags that need to be applied to a given snapshot - by aggregating tags we ensure that ec2-create-tags is called only onece
  snapshot_tags="Key=CreatedBy,Value=ec2-automate-backup"
  #if $name_tag_create is true then append ec2ab_${ebs_selected}_$current_date to the variable $snapshot_tags
  if $name_tag_create; then
    snapshot_tags="$snapshot_tags Key=Name,Value=ec2ab_${ebs_selected}_$current_date"
  fi
  #if $hostname_tag_create is true then append --tag InitiatingHost=$(hostname -f) to the variable $snapshot_tags
  if $hostname_tag_create; then
    snapshot_tags="$snapshot_tags Key=InitiatingHost,Value='$(hostname -s)'"
  fi
  #if $purge_after_date_fe is true, then append $purge_after_date_fe to the variable $snapshot_tags
  if [[ -n $purge_after_date_fe ]]; then
    snapshot_tags="$snapshot_tags Key=PurgeAfterFE,Value=$purge_after_date_fe Key=PurgeAllow,Value=true"
  fi
  #if $user_tags is true, then append Volume=$ebs_selected and Created=$current_date to the variable $snapshot_tags
  if $user_tags; then
    snapshot_tags="$snapshot_tags Key=Volume,Value=${ebs_selected} Key=Created,Value=$current_date"
  fi
  #if $snapshot_tags is not zero length then set the tag on the snapshot using aws ec2 create-tags
  if [[ -n $snapshot_tags ]]; then
    echo "Tagging Snapshot $ec2_snapshot_resource_id with the following Tags: $snapshot_tags"
    tags_argument="--tags $snapshot_tags"
    aws_ec2_create_tag_result=$(aws ec2 create-tags --resources $ec2_snapshot_resource_id --region $region $tags_argument --output text 2>&1)
  fi
}

get_date_binary() {
  #$(uname -o) (operating system) would be ideal, but OS X / Darwin does not support to -o option
  #$(uname) on OS X defaults to $(uname -s) and $(uname) on GNU/Linux defaults to $(uname -s)
  uname_result=$(uname)
  case $uname_result in
    Darwin) date_binary="posix" ;;
    FreeBSD) date_binary="posix" ;;
    Linux) date_binary="linux-gnu" ;;
    *) date_binary="unknown" ;;
  esac
}

get_purge_after_date_fe() {
case $purge_after_input in
  #any number of numbers followed by a letter "d" or "days" multiplied by 86400 (number of seconds in a day)
  [0-9]*d) purge_after_value_seconds=$(( ${purge_after_input%?} * 86400 )) ;;
  #any number of numbers followed by a letter "h" or "hours" multiplied by 3600 (number of seconds in an hour)
  [0-9]*h) purge_after_value_seconds=$(( ${purge_after_input%?} * 3600 )) ;;
  #any number of numbers followed by a letter "m" or "minutes" multiplied by 60 (number of seconds in a minute)
  [0-9]*m) purge_after_value_seconds=$(( ${purge_after_input%?} * 60 ));;
  #no trailing digits default is days - multiply by 86400 (number of minutes in a day)
  *) purge_after_value_seconds=$(( $purge_after_input * 86400 ));;
esac
#based on the date_binary variable, the case statement below will determine the method to use to determine "purge_after_days" in the future
case $date_binary in
  linux-gnu) echo $(date -d +${purge_after_value_seconds}sec -u +%s) ;;
  posix) echo $(date -v +${purge_after_value_seconds}S -u +%s) ;;
  *) echo $(date -d +${purge_after_value_seconds}sec -u +%s) ;;
esac
}

purge_EBS_Snapshots() {
  # snapshot_purge_allowed is a string containing the SnapshotIDs of snapshots
  # that contain a tag with the key value/pair PurgeAllow=true
  snapshot_purge_allowed=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --region $region --filters Name=tag:PurgeAllow,Values=true --output text --query 'Snapshots[*].SnapshotId')

  for snapshot_id_evaluated in $snapshot_purge_allowed; do
    #gets the "PurgeAfterFE" date which is in UTC with UNIX Time format (or xxxxxxxxxx / %s)
    purge_after_fe=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --region $region --snapshot-ids $snapshot_id_evaluated --output text | grep ^TAGS.*PurgeAfterFE | cut -f 3)
    #if purge_after_date is not set then we have a problem. Need to alert user.
    if [[ -z $purge_after_fe ]]; then
      #Alerts user to the fact that a Snapshot was found with PurgeAllow=true but with no PurgeAfterFE date.
      echo "Snapshot with the Snapshot ID \"$snapshot_id_evaluated\" has the tag \"PurgeAllow=true\" but does not have a \"PurgeAfterFE=xxxxxxxxxx\" key/value pair. $app_name is unable to determine if $snapshot_id_evaluated should be purged." 1>&2
    else
      # if $purge_after_fe is less than $current_date then
      # PurgeAfterFE is earlier than the current date
      # and the snapshot can be safely purged
      if [[ $purge_after_fe < $current_date ]]; then
        echo "Snapshot \"$snapshot_id_evaluated\" with the PurgeAfterFE date of \"$purge_after_fe\" will be deleted."
        aws_ec2_delete_snapshot_result=$(aws ec2 delete-snapshot --region $region --snapshot-id $snapshot_id_evaluated --output text 2>&1)
      fi
    fi
  done
}

#calls prerequisitecheck function to ensure that all executables required for script execution are available
prerequisite_check

app_name=$(basename $0)
#sets defaults
selection_method="volumeid"
#date_binary allows a user to set the "date" binary that is installed on their system and, therefore, the options that will be given to the date binary to perform date calculations
date_binary=""
#sets the "Name" tag set for a snapshot to false - using "Name" requires that ec2-create-tags be called in addition to ec2-create-snapshot
name_tag_create=false
#sets the "InitiatingHost" tag set for a snapshot to false
hostname_tag_create=false
#sets the user_tags feature to false - user_tag creates tags on snapshots - by default each snapshot is tagged with volume_id and current_date timestamp
user_tags=false
#sets the Purge Snapshot feature to false - if purge_snapshots=true then snapshots will be purged
purge_snapshots=false
#handles options processing

while getopts :s:c:r:v:t:k:pnhu opt; do
  case $opt in
    s) selection_method="$OPTARG" ;;
    c) cron_primer="$OPTARG" ;;
    r) region="$OPTARG" ;;
    v) volumeid="$OPTARG" ;;
    t) tag="$OPTARG" ;;
    k) purge_after_input="$OPTARG" ;;
    n) name_tag_create=true ;;
    h) hostname_tag_create=true ;;
    p) purge_snapshots=true ;;
    u) user_tags=true ;;
    *) echo "Error with Options Input. Cause of failure is most likely that an unsupported parameter was passed or a parameter was passed without a corresponding option." 1>&2 ; exit 64 ;;
  esac
done

#sources "cron_primer" file for running under cron or other restricted environments - this file should contain the variables and environment configuration required for ec2-automate-backup to run correctly
if [[ -n $cron_primer ]]; then
  if [[ -f $cron_primer ]]; then
    source $cron_primer
  else
    echo "Cron Primer File \"$cron_primer\" Could Not Be Found." 1>&2 ; exit 70
  fi
fi

#if region is not set then:
if [[ -z $region ]]; then
  #if the environment variable $EC2_REGION is not set set to us-east-1
  if [[ -z $EC2_REGION ]]; then
    region="us-east-1"
  else
    region=$EC2_REGION
  fi
fi

#sets date variable
current_date=$(date -u +%s)

#sets the PurgeAfterFE tag to the number of seconds that a snapshot should be retained
if [[ -n $purge_after_input ]]; then
  #if the date_binary is not set, call the get_date_binary function
  if [[ -z $date_binary ]]; then
    get_date_binary
  fi
  purge_after_date_fe=$(get_purge_after_date_fe)
  echo "Snapshots taken by $app_name will be eligible for purging after the following date (the purge after date given in seconds from epoch): $purge_after_date_fe."
fi

#get_EBS_List gets a list of EBS instances for which a snapshot is desired. The list of EBS instances depends upon the selection_method that is provided by user input
get_EBS_List

#the loop below is called once for each volume in $ebs_backup_list - the currently selected EBS volume is passed in as "ebs_selected"
for ebs_selected in $ebs_backup_list; do
  ec2_snapshot_description="ec2ab_${ebs_selected}_$current_date"
  ec2_snapshot_resource_id=$(aws ec2 create-snapshot --region $region --description $ec2_snapshot_description --volume-id $ebs_selected --output text --query SnapshotId 2>&1)
  if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then
    echo -e "An error occurred when running ec2-create-snapshot. The error returned is below:\n$ec2_create_snapshot_result" 1>&2 ; exit 70
  fi  
  create_EBS_Snapshot_Tags
done

#if purge_snapshots is true, then run purge_EBS_Snapshots function
if $purge_snapshots; then
  echo "Snapshot Purging is Starting Now."
  purge_EBS_Snapshots
fi
```

The cron primer file used is the following (cron-primer.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash -
# EC2_HOME required for EC2 API Tools
export EC2_HOME=/usr/local/ec2/apitools
# JAVA_HOME required for EC2 API Tools
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/
# export PATH=/bin is required for cut, date, grep
# export PATH=/opt/aws/bin/ is required for EC2 API Tools
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/ec2/apitools/bin/
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_KEY=XXXXXX
# The environmental variable names seem to have changed
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXX
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXXX
```

(Note that the only environmental variables that should be required are the AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, but I left the others as they had been used by the older EC2 CLI implementation)

The script runs perfectly when done so directly from the console, but when I run the script from a cronjob it does not work. The following error is emailed:

```
In order to use , the executable "aws" must be installed.
```

Note that this error is from the 8th line in the script. The message infers that the aws executable could not be found, but there is a symlink in /usr/local/bin to this file which is included in the PATH variable. Also, one can see that the $0 variable ($app_name) seems to be empty as it is not printing. (This same error printed correctly  when run from the console before I had AWS CLI installed properly, so I know there is no error in the script itself)

The crontab looks as follows:

```
8 * * * * /usr/local/ec2/scripts/ec2-automate-backup.sh -r eu-west-1 -s tag -t "Backup,Values=true" -k 7 -p -n -c /usr/local/ec2/scripts/cron-primer.sh
```

Also, I would like to rather output the results of the script to a file, to do this I had the cronjob as

```
8 * * * * /usr/local/ec2/scripts/ec2-automate-backup.sh -r eu-west-1 -s tag -t "Backup,Values=true" -k 1 -p -n -c /usr/local/ec2/scripts/cron-primer.sh &> /var/log/ebs_backup/ec2-automate-backup_`date +"%Y%m%d"`.log
```

Which did not create the file, if someone could highlight the reason for the file not being created (permissions in the destination folder is correct), it would be appreciated

Comment: Please work your way through the duplicate above it will help you solve your problem. Hint: aws is not in the standard PATH.

Comment: You also call `prerequisite_check` before defining `app_name`, which answers your title question.

Comment: What confuses me on that is that i had gotten this error before when AWS CLI was actually not installed. It did print the $app_name out correctly then...

Comment: Ok, I see what happened with the $app_name variable not having a value.  It is indeed the case that it had not been assigned a value before calling the function, the reason it worked before when I had run the script from the console was that the first call set the variable and subsequent calls had been during the same calls, so the variable already had a value.

Comment: The issue then seems to be related to the PATH not being set. Why would it be the case if I do set the variable in the cron primer script? Should I rather set the variables in the crontab? The cron primer method follows the way as recommended by the script author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `prerequisite_check` definition says, `basename, cut, date` and `aws` commands should be available.

Script is unable to find `aws` command when running from `crontab`. Hence, you are hitting error.

In `crontab`, you need to modify PATH variable to include `path` to `aws` executable, by writing them before your `cron` lines.

You can use below syntax to add `path` variable in `crontab`.

```
~]$ crontab -l
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
50 1 * * * sh /home/user/mybackupjob.sh
```

Comment: The script supports linking a cron primer file, in which you should set environmental variables such as PATH. The PATH as set by the indicated cron primer file should be correct, as there is a symlink in /usr/local/bin (which is set in the PATH) to the folder that contains the aws executable. This same cron primer is used when the script is run from the console and the PATH seems to be correct then. Is the fact that $0 is empty not a smoking gun for another issue?

Comment: Ok, I see what happened with the $app_name variable not having a value.  It is indeed the case that it had not been assigned a value before calling the function, the reason it worked before when I had run the script from the console was that the first call set the variable and subsequent calls had been during the same calls, so the variable already had a value.

Comment: The issue then seems to be related to the PATH not being set. Why would it be the case if I do set the variable in the cron primer script? Should I rather set the variables in the crontab? The cron primer method follows the way as recommended by the script author

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the issue had been linked to the line

```
prerequisite_check
```

in the script which was placed before all variables had been setup. I moved the check down to below the point where the cron primer is linked and everything worked fine. It is strange that a script so commonly used has such an error without anyone reporting it. I assume the bug had been introduced in a recent update

So in short, the symptoms described had been linked to the PATH variable not being set, the reason it was not being set was due to an error in the used script.